# Problemas com Utf-8 no servidor com Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, vraptor

Boa tarde, estou com um problema de de acentuações com minha aplicação rodando o servidor Ubuntu 14.04 VPS americano. Toda a aplicação rodando em minha máquina de desenvolvimento estão cadastrando normalmente na base junto a acentuação.

Fiz um backup da minha base local e levei até o servidor, a aplicação rodando de la, busca normalmente os dados com acentuação do banco, mais se eu fazer uma nova adição pela página web, ele adiciona uns quadrados com ? no local.

O que pode ser? meu mysql instalado errado? existe mais alguma configuração alem a da setada na criação da base?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Para deixar claro para quem estiver com o mesmo problema e já tiver modificado tudo.

Ao configurar meu tomcat, alguns argumentos foram passados para a VM, e faltava os seguintes argumentos:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
```

Eu realmente achei estranho o fato do banco aceitar os acentos, e a pagina trazer os acentos para a tela, mais não conseguir cadastrar os acentos.

Mais era isso ai.

Obrigado.